# Can't choose between Radio buttons

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following form code but I cannot choose between these for choices. 
I can't figure where is the problem. all i know about radio buttons is that they need to have the same name

```
 <div class="controls">
      <input type="radio" name="pub_place" id="1" value="1" >1
      <input type="radio" name="pub_place" id="2" value="2" >2
      <input type="radio" name="pub_place" id="3" value="3" >3
      <input type="radio" name="pub_place" id="4" value="3" >4
 </div>
```

this is all the view

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url('/save-publicity')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="date01">Publicity Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="pub_name" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="date01">website Link</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="pub_link" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="fileInput">Publicity Image</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="input-file uniform_on" name="pub_image" id="pub_image" type="file" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group hidden-phone">
                <label class="control-label" for="textarea2">Publication status </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="pub_status" value="1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group hidden-phone">
                <label class="control-label" for="textarea2">Pub Place </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="radio" name="pub_place" id="1" value="1" >1
                    <input type="radio" name="pub_place" id="2" value="2" >2
                    <input type="radio" name="pub_place" id="3" value="3" >3
                    <input type="radio" name="pub_place" id="4" value="4" >4
                </div>
                <p>NB:  <strong>Place 1 dimension:</strong> 1170x150 |
                <strong>Place 2 dimension:</strong> 850x100 |
                <strong>Place 3 and 4 dimension:</strong>  270x329</p>
                <img style="width:300px"src="backend/brunch.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Publicity</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

[image: you can see here the 4 buttons. there is no check when I click on one of them]

they keep giving me NULL on  the column pub_place on my database

Comment: What have you tried and what is your issue exactly?
I assume this is only a part of your form, because there are only inputs with no form itself

Comment: i am going to update all the view. my problem is that i can't choose between this choices. therare the 4 choices but there is no checked when i click one of the radio buttons

Comment: what do you mean you cannot choose? The controls seem to function properly. are you not getting the values from a POST?

Comment: Do you click on the number next to the radio or do you click directly on the radio? If you click on the number, then it will not check, since there is no label tag wrapping the radio input In that the case, you can do this for each radio

    ...
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="pub_place" id="1" value="1" >1
    </label>
    ...

Comment: I updated a picture of the 4 radio. i click on the radio not the number. but there is no response.

Comment: @AimenQaissouni i run your code in my pc and what can i see,  Check [screenshot](https://prntscr.com/m110ni)

Comment: I have no idea why radio buttons. well i worked with select instead and it worked fine for me. but i really want to know why radio doesnt work

Comment: a html form needs to send data to the database, maybe you could rather show us the API call code and the network request body, then we could help you debug.

Comment: There may be an overlay element over the radio preventing you from clicking it or a javascript code preventing the radio from checking.
To debug, use inspect element in your browser.

Comment: You can not have same name otherwise you will never know which radio button clicked.